# Call objects in array values

Tags: php, arrays, object

I set an array variable like this:

```
$app = [

  "page" => function(){
    echo "OK";
  },

  "test" => function(){
    testFunc();
  },

];
```

Now, I want to know how can I call or run the objects in array,

I trying to use `eval($app['test'])` but not work!

Comment: *I call or run the objects in array* Which objects ? I don't see any object in your array

Comment: @Rizier123 the value of arrays are closures object.

Comment: You get a point for that :) Then I think you got your answers below.

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks ;) , Yes but I cannot accept answer now, I should wait 9 minutes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

ie.

```
call_user_func($app['page']);
```